# What would be the inequalities for this double integral exercise?

Tags: integration

I have the following exercise and I can't understand how to infer the inequalities to solve the double integral.

How do I know if x is simply between 2 and 14 (according to the points) or if I have to use the given equations?

"Let $d(x,y)$ be the density - in $g/cm^2$ - of a thin plate at point $(x, y)$, being the plate of shape of a region $R$. We can show that the mass $M$ - in g - of this plate is given by $M = \int \int_{R}{d(x,y) dA}$.

Consider a plate of density $d(x,y) = 4y$ in the shape of a triangle with vertices $A(2,4)$, $B(6,8)$ and $C(14,4)$. Knowing that the equations of lines $AB$, $BC$ and $AC$ are, respectively, $x - y + 2 = 0$, $x + 2y - 22 = 0$ and $y - 4 = 0$, we can conclude that the mass of this plate in grams is:"

[image: graph]

Comment: With double integrals (and triple, of course), you should start by drawing the region. What is the the range of $x$ values in your region? And, for fixed $x$, a vertical line enters the region at $y=...$ and exits at $y=...$ ? (I don't think they should have given you the equations, as that's part of what you should be figuring out ... But you are correct that $2\le x\le 14$.

Comment: OK, so this is progress. So what do you have for your integral(s)?

Comment: If the range for x is $2 \leq x \leq 14$, is the y range $4 \leq y \leq x − y + 2$ or $4 \leq y \leq x + 2y - 22$ or none of these? That's my doubt.

Comment: No, you need to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$. The problem is that there are two different formulas, one when $2\le x\le 6$ and another when $6\le x\le 14$. So you need to write two different integrals. It's easier to set this problem up as $\int\int dx\,dy$, rather than $\int\int dy\,dx$. (You need some basic practice setting up double integrals.)